# Why this code doesnt work? (c++ OOP) public inherits

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I would like some help explaining this phenomenom:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void m() {cout<<"A::m "<<this<<endl;};
};

class B1:  public A
{
public:
    void m() {cout<<"B::m "<<this<<endl;};
};

class B2:  public A ,public B1
{
};

class D : public B2
{};

int main()
{
    B2 b;
    D d;
    A* a = &b; // Row 27
    //error: a = &d;  Base class 'A' is ambiguous // Row 28
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the code in Row27  work but the code in Row28 doesnt?
Thank in advance!

**Note:** I am well aware of virtual inheritance, I just want to know what is the difference between Row27 and Row28 - why one throw a compilation error when the other not?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: It doesnt' apply here, otherwise Row27 will not work either! what is the difference betwwen row27 and row 28?

Comment: what compiler are you using? Row 27 doesn't compile either here

Comment: Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Comment: VS2010 does indeed compile it, but issues a *warning* which suggests it is ignoring `B2`'s inheritance from `A`. this is why Row 27 works. I think this is a weird behavior of VS2010 and I don't know if there is a way to turn it off (other than considering all warnings as errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using non-virtual inheritance to derive from `A`, which indirectly creates two sub-objects of type `A` in every object of type `D`. The compiler cannot disambiguate which sub-object you refer to when doing the pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base conversion, and issues an error.

In order to have only one sub-object of type `A` generated for objects of type `D`, you have to make inheritance from `A` virtual along the inheritance paths which make `D` derive from `A`:

```
class B1:  virtual public A
{
    // ...
};

class B2:  virtual public A, public B1
{
};
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to compile your example on Visual Studio 2010 SP1, which gives me a *warning* about the definition of `B2`:

```
class B2: public A, public B1
{
};

1>sotest.cpp(18): warning C4584: 'B2' : base-class 'A' is already a base-class of 'B1'
1>          sotest.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'A'
1>          sotest.cpp(11) : see declaration of 'B1'
```

In other words, for some reason VC10 seems to consider the inheritance from `A` redundant and *ignores it*. This is why the assignment `A* a = &b;` compiles: `class B2` actually inherits from `A` only once (through `B1`). The same is not true of `D`, because VC10 has probably no redundant inheritance to ignore, and `D` effectively inherits from `A` twice (through `B1` and through `B2`).

I ignore the reasons why VC10 behaves this way, and I do not know if there is a compiler option to suppress this behavior. Remarkably, both GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2 **refuse** to compile the assignment `A* a = &b;`.

Comment: then why the code in Row27 work? why it doesnt require virtual inheritance!? B2 has the same amount of 'A' just like 'D'!

Comment: @user1997873: does it really work? I just tried it on GCC 4.7.1 and Clang 3.2 and i get a compiler error unless I use virtual inheritance. what compiler are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Comment: So this answer is basically "I don't know"

Comment: I've been lurking and I'm confused -- if VC10 is ignoring the redundant inheritance of A in B2, then the inheritance hierarchy looks like this: A -> B1 -> B2 -> D, right? But that shouldn't cause any problems, that's just a normal inheritance hierarchy. So doesn't it seem like VC10 is behaving inconsistently then? Ignoring the inheritance from A when B2 is declared (and giving B2 only one copy of A's members), but still giving D two copies of A's members?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: no, this answer is "VS shouldn't behave like that and I don't know why it does".

Comment: @AndyProwl: I was close :D

Comment: @Emily: just because VC10 doesn't ignore it. There are two instances of A in memory.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: with respect, no, not really. the user asked "why does Row28 not compile?", and i explained why. so my answer could have been complete already. then he asked a further question: "why does Row27 compile?", and i also answered how things should be *theoretically*, and why they are not so (VC10 has a weird behavior). to the question "why does VC10 have a weird behavior?" my answer is "i don't know". this whole thing is quite different from "basically i don't know"

Comment: @Emily: indeed it seems to behave inconsistently

Comment: @AndyT, to clarify the inconsistency: This answer is saying that VC ignores the redundant inheritance of A in B2, so a B2 instance contains a single A instance. If this is in fact what's going on, then a D instance should contain a single B2 instance (which contains a single A instance), so there should only be one A instance inside a D instance. So then `A* a = &d` should not be ambiguous -- but VC says it is ambiguous. So apparently a D object contains a B2 object with 2 A instances inside it, but a B2 object contains only a single A2 instance, which is very odd!

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit: i suggest you to revise your sense of topology then :-)

Answer (score 1):

For future users it seems:

I just tried it on GCC 4.7.1 and Clang 3.2 and i get a compiler error unless I use virtual inheritance. what compiler are you using? – Andy Prowl

VS2010 does indeed compile, but issues a warning which suggests it is ignoring B2's inheritance from A. this is why Row 27 works. I think this is a weird behavior of VS2010 and I don't know if there is a way to turn it off (other than considering all warnings as errors) – Andy Prowl

thank you @Andy Prowl.